# How to close obvious duplicate

Tags: support, bounty, exact-duplicates

This question [How to access the Menu Mnemonics of an X11 Program within macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340265/how-to-access-the-menu-mnemonics-of-an-x11-program-within-macos) is and obvious duplicate of [How can I get the Alt key to work in an X11 application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13745/how-can-i-get-the-alt-key-to-work-in-an-x11-application?rq=1)

However I can't mark the question as a duplicate as it has a bounty. and one of the answers is simply a link to the other question.

These seems rather odd as surely we would want any bounty to go to the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, I've reached out to the user. Moderators can cancel bounties if needed.

Comment: Good plan. Even if the OP wants the bounty to play out, closure can happen after it’s awarded and expired.